# Cannot uninstall internet explorer 11 (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

This question is not about removing a virus. I tried removing the virus using all of the methods recommended by various websites for several hours.

This is about how to uninstall/reinstall IE 11 because I cannot find this virus and have already uninstalled every part of IE11 I can and cannot reinstall it because MS is telling me it is still there.

My internet explorer 11 got hijacked by some sort of malware that made it open up with what looked like a google search for "remove+everything+else". I couldn't find any information about this problem, and the terms make searching difficult.

IE also disappeared from my list of programs in the "uninstall programs" list, and from the programs folder, but appeared as a separate folder at the same level as the programs folder.

I deleted all of the files in the folder except the "en-US" folder that contains .mui language files. I can't figure out how to get rid of this.

I downloaded IE from the MS site and have been trying to install it again, but am being told it is still there. I tried turning IE off using "windows features" and that didn't work. Turning it back on didn't work either.

I also tried the MS advice here: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=318378 
Nothing about IE appears in the "installed updates"

I've asked for help at the MS support website and the advice I've been given is that I **can't** uninstall IE from my computer.

I'm pretty sure I did this in the past on the same computer because I didn't use it, and then installed it again when I needed it for work. This also seems like the "automatic bundling" that MS got the antitrust investigation for.

Can I uninstall IE and reinstall it, and if so how?

Comment: For uninstalling IE11, this is your only option http://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Internet-Explorer-11-for-Windows-7 and once you've done this then I recommend thoroughly cleaning your PC with Malwarebytes, some antivirus like Kaspersky, and maybe even run [ComboFix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/). Most importantly, consider [Nuking it from orbit](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/24195/64787)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, if this gets reopened, you might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 I have yet to personally see a question re-opened on any StackExchange site, lol. I won't be holding my breath for this one.

Answer (score -1):

You basically can't uninstall IE since it's a core part of Windows.  If things like Malwarebytes or SAS can't get rid of it, you're probably looking at doing a clean install of Windows.

Comment: That is outdated. Since IE9 at least, it is uninstallable. That might not solve the issue, though.

Comment: You can downgrade back to IE9 by "removing" IE11, but you can't completely remove IE from the computer.